# How to include graphics inside the section name

Tags: graphics, sectioning

I am trying to insert an icon (a `pdf` file) literally next to the section name.

[image]

I want the little shield icon to be where the `<Icon>` is.

The code to generate this image is:

```
\subsection{Sentinel $<$Icon$>$}\icon{static/sentinel.pdf}
```

If I try to add the `\icon` inside the `\subsection`:

```
\subsection{Sentinel \icon{static/sentinel.pdf}}
```

I get an error.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
               \csname\endcsname 
l.42 ...ction{Sentinel \icon{static/sentinel.pdf}}                                                  
? 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname 
l.42 ...ction{Sentinel \icon{static/sentinel.pdf}}
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on generated//manual.log.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

If possible it would be nice that the icon doesn't appear in the table of content and that the link from the table of content continues to work.

`\icon` is defined by

```
\newcommand{\icon}[1]{\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[height=12pt,keepaspectratio]{#1}}%
\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I suspect `\protect\icon{static/sentinel.pdf}` should work. However, you will get into troubles with bookmarks, if `hyperref` is used

Comment: Yeah it does, even in the table of content with hyperref, but I'd prefer if there was a way that it wouldn't appear at all in the table of content.

Comment: Use `\subsection[title for the toc]{\protect\icon{....}}` then. The sectioning commands (at least of standard classes) all have an optional first argument for providing a shorter title (or optional title) which enters the toc and the mandatory argument for the really header of the chapter, section etc. My concern was rather the complaints by `hyperref` about non-allowed tokens in the PDFString issue. There should be a `\texorpdfstring{\protect\icon{}}{}` command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need some `\protect`ion. BTW, that complicated `\newcommand` can be simplified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\icon}[1]{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section here}
  \subsection{Sentinel \protect\icon{example-image-a}}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to `\protect` at many instances, you have these possibilities. First make it `robust` using `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\icon}[1]{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{#1}}
\robustify{\icon}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section here}
  \subsection{Sentinel \icon{example-image-a}}
\end{document}
```

Or use `\newrobustcmd` (from `etoolbox` again) like

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\icon}[1]{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{#1}}
```

Or use an optional argument like

```
\subsection[<opt argument>]{Sentinel \icon{example-image-a}}
```

etc....

If you are using `hyperref` you may need to use `\texorpdfstring{\icon{example-image-a}}{}` to get rid of the warning and the aftermath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newrobustcmd{\icon}[1]{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section here}
  \subsection{Sentinel \texorpdfstring{\icon{example-image-a}}{}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's easy, but i more question. Do i not need the keepaspectratio to make sure it stays intact ?
and 2: is there a way that the icon does not appear in the table of content ?

Comment: @user2475269 First, when you specify only the `height` (or `width`) the aspect ratio is maintained. You need `keepaspectratio` only when you specify both `width` and `height`. Second, you can use an optional argument for sub section like `\subsection[Sentinel]{Sentinel \icon{example-image-a}}` so that picture doesn't appear in toc or heading etc.

Comment: Great, I'm accepting as soon as i can