# How can I insert an icon in a section header that scales with font size depending on where it appears in the document?

Tags: graphics, fontsize, scaling

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239360/how-to-include-graphics-inside-the-section-name) question which lays out how to correctly insert an icon into a section header. However, it does so at a fixed size and appears in the TOC, which has a different font size, which looks a bit awkward. Is there a simple tweak to the command that will scale the size of the icon with the local font size?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\icon}[1]{\includegraphics[height=12pt]{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section here}
  \subsection{Sentinel \protect\icon{example-image-a}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a font-based length, like `ex` or `em`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\icon}[1]{\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Some section here \protect\icon{example-image}}
\subsection{Sentinel \protect\icon{example-image}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect. So many options to remember, the obvious ones sometimes escape you...